# Why is this a poor approach to estimating impact energy?

Tags: energy, collision

I want to estimate the energy dissipated during an impact between 2 bumper cars, for example if I will be selecting a bumper for one of the cars which can dissipate this energy.
Some background: assume cars are of different sizes, the impact is head-on (not at an angle), the cars do not stick together after collision yet do not rebound perfectly so there is some energy dissipated in the bumpers, and the cars may be accelerating. I can measure the relative velocity $v$ between the cars but not each car's individual velocity, and from the car's masses $M_1$ and $M_2$ I can estimate the effective mass of collision $M_{eff}={M_1M_2}/({M1+M2})$. A colleague mentioned that $\frac{1}{2}M_{eff}{v^2}$ is a poor estimate of the impact energy because the velocity is not measured in an inertial frame of reference, but later he thought that $\frac{1}{2}M_{eff}{v^2}$ would apply. If you can help me with a simple explanation of whether $\frac{1}{2}M_{eff}{v^2}$ is legitimate here, I would appreciate it.

Comment: To answer you question you need to investigate how the design of Formula One cars converts the kinetic energy of the car into other forms of energy. https://www.formula1.com/en/latest/headlines/2016/8/belgian-race-red-flagged-after-huge-magnussen-crash.html

Comment: By "impact energy", do you mean the total energy of the collision, or the remaining energy after the bumper has done its work? If you mean the first thing, the standard kinetic energy seems indeed like the quantity you are after.

Comment: By impact energy I mean the energy that the Escalade bumper must be designed to dissipate, i.e. before the bumper does its work. [My limited understanding of the problem is probably preventing me from describing it well].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt:

The initial momentum is

$$p_0 = M_e v_0$$

After collision, assuming the cars stick together, the final common speed is

$$v_1 = \frac{M_e}{M_e+M_m} v_0$$

where I've used conservation of momentum. The initial kinetic energy is

$$E_0 = \frac{1}{2} M_e v_0^2$$

while the final kinetic energy is

$$E_1 = \frac{1}{2} (M_e + M_m) v_1^2$$

which means the bumper has dissipated energy

$$E_b = \frac{1}{2}[M_e v_0^2 - (M_e + M_m)v_1^2]$$

but this is just

$$E_b = E_0\left(1 - \frac{M_e}{M_e+M_m}\right).$$

Note $E_b \ne E_0$, which is possibly what you were referring to. This assumes a "perfect bumper", which is able to make the collision maximally inelastic. If the bumper is unable to dissipate energy $E_b$, the cars won't stick together and more energy will be transferred ($E_1$ will be larger).

Comment: Very helpful! The cars do not stick together after the collision so I have added that information to the question. How close do you think your Eb estimate is to the real dissipation? Is it a lot higher or lower, or is it pretty close? I am asking because I think this is the only Eb estimate I can calculate from the measurements and information I have.

Comment: $E_b$ is the maximum theoretical value for the dissipation (neglecting, however, friction from the road etc). If the cars do not stick together, the collision is more approximately elastic, so $E_b$ will be smaller.

Feel free to upvote the answer if you find it helpful :)

Comment: If the cars collide in such a way that their centres of mass and velocity are not all in a line, some energy will be converted to set them into rotation, which will also change things.

Comment: The collision is inline, so there is no rotation afterward. I edited the question.

Comment: So sorry to make a major update to question, but a colleague pointed out the issue is that my velocity measurements are not relative to an inertial frame of reference. [Still would love some help understanding this though.]

Comment: Unless the Mini is initially accelerating for some reason, the frame in which it is initially at rest ought to be inertial, shouldn't it?